# Is it possible to get rid of content duplicates?

Tags: domain-access

I've got a site, mysite.com. Now I'm trying to add blog on it at sub-domain, blog.mysite.com, using the Domain Access module.

When I create an article in blog, with alias blog.mysite.com/article-alias, it is available from main site, by URL mysite.com/article-alias. At the same time, main site articles, like mysite.com/about are available from blog by URL blog.mysite.com/about. No matter which affiliate I'm sending this article to, or which source site I choose, it still happens. Today, I've found that some of such pages were indexed by Google as duplicates, despite having canonical tag.

Is it possible to get rid of such pages with this module settings, or with the help of some additional modules? Still, I can't find no solution.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. I manage two domains with domain access: in.domain.at and out.domain.at. I have created a node with ID 1 and assigned it to ```in.domain.at``` but the node is also accessible through ```out.domain.at```. so both
```in.domain.at/node/1``` and
```out.domain.at/node/1``` show the same content. I don't know whether this is  how domain access works. I would expect ```out.domain.at/node/1``` to not show any content but a 403 or 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your Robots.txt file through Drupal using [RobotsTxt](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt) module. This way you can exclude whatever content you want from Google, etc.